# C++11: Undefined symbols for arcitechture

Tags: c++11

I'm having a weird problem (at least in my eyes) with C++. I've created a thread pool class, and in the main function I just pushes one element to the task queue.
This gives me an error saying "undefined symbols". When the specific line is commented out, the program compiles.

Here is the `push` method in question:

```
template<class F, class ...Args>
void concurrency::thread_pool::push(F&& f, Args&&... args) {
    if (stop) {
        throw std::runtime_error("push on stopped thread_pool");
    }

    std::function<void()> func = std::bind(f, args...);

    lockGuard l(mutex);

    bool should_wake = queue.empty();

    queue.push(func);

    if (should_wake) {
        cond.notify_one();
    }
}
```

And here's the main function:

```
void hello_world() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    pool = new concurrency::thread_pool(5);
    pool->push(hello_world); // <-- Compile error!
}
```

This is the command:

```
david$ g++ -g -Wall -std=c++0x -I ./ *.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "void concurrency::thread_pool::push<void (&)()>(void (&)())", referenced from:
      _main in ccuKcG16.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And my g++ version:

```
davids-mbp:cpp-thread-pool david$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc47/4.7.3/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2/4.7.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc47 /4.7.3 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++ --program-suffix=-4.7 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp4 --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr2 --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc08 --with-ppl=/usr/local/opt/ppl011 --with-cloog=/usr/local/opt/cloog-ppl015 --with-system-zlib --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-stage1-checking --enable-checking=release --enable-lto --disable-werror --enable-plugin --disable-nls --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.3 (GCC)
```

### Update

- thread_pool.hpp: http://pastebin.com/62SDD0ZY
- thread_pool.cpp: http://pastebin.com/nqz57HS9

Comment: Did you try with std=c++11 ?

Comment: With OS X Mavericks this is a known issue. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/16352833/

Comment: Maybe it's worthwhile upgrading to gcc-4.8.2 (release) with homebrew / macports?

Comment: Where is defined `void concurrency::thread_pool::push(F&& f, Args&&... args)` ? in a .cpp (see [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) ) ? or in .h, .inl ?

Comment: It's defined in `thread_pool.hpp` first. Should the "template<class F, class Args...>" be left out in the definition in the `.cpp`?

Comment: The entire body of the implementation of the templated function should be in the `hpp` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem might be reduced to

- [g++ linking order dependency when linking c code to c++ code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363398/g-linking-order-dependency-when-linking-c-code-)

Because you use `*.cpp` in your command line

## Update

I'm afraid your post doesn't provide enought information, but I bet your problem is

- [Storing C++ template function definitions in a .CPP file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)

Comment: I've tried to list `thread_pool.cpp` before and after `main.cpp` but still no go. I can compile the program, but same errors occurs when linking.

Comment: I've updated my original post with definition of both the header file and cpp file.

Comment: Update! When I took the whole definition of the ´push´ function from the cpp file to the header file - it worked! Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.