# Cmake error while building a package

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Ok, I have no clue what is going on? I am just following some instructions (apparently for ubuntu OS) on my macbook.

Everything was going fine until the last step.

When I do `make`, I see the following error:

```
Linking CXX executable ../../bin/test-wordcount
ld: warning: path '/usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.dylib' following -L not a directory
ld: warning: path '/usr/local/lib/libzmq.dylib' following -L not a directory
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_del_curterm", referenced from:
      terminalHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o)
  "_set_curterm", referenced from:
      terminalHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o)
  "_setupterm", referenced from:
      terminalHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o)
  "_tigetnum", referenced from:
      terminalHasColors(int) in libLLVMSupport.a(Process.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [bin/test-wordcount] Error 1
make[1]: *** [test/wordcount/CMakeFiles/test-wordcount.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What am i missing?

My Cmakelists.txt file
http://collabedit.com/8vc7s

Comment: Is that your own project? If not, what project in what version is it? If it is your own, try to replace the `-L` by `-l` (lower case L) in your CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @user2799037: I dont see any -L in my CMakeLists.txt :(

Comment: How do you add your library? It should be done with `add_library CMake will add the right -L/-l automatically.

Comment: @user2799037 : My apologies for annoying.. But here is my file : http://collabedit.com/8vc7s

What should i add... where should i add..

Comment: I cannot access your link. In general it is better to post your relevant parts of the source into the question by editing it. Maybe your problem is unrelated to the warning. You mention in one of your comments OS X. Maybe this is your problem, too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16352833

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old stack but it shows up in the first few search hits when seeking solution for this problem.

In OSX you might have to add "ncurses" to your target link libraries. I.e.:

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES ( myProject ncurses
                        ${LLVM_LIBRARY}
                        [... all of your libraries])

Answer (score 1):

You are using header term.h, but the library that contains these (exported) symbols (del_curterm, ...) is not on your LD path  [term.h](http://code-reference.com/c/term.h). Find the library that has it for your platform, install it and add list it in -L swich.

Also see the ld warning about unexisting directories

Comment: Thanks for responding.. I am using mountain lion OSX.. ? How do i install term.h for my platform and where do I add -L switch.. sorry for asking such basic questions

Comment: Try the package manager for your system (i do not have that OS). -L swich is added by CMAKE, but probably the installed package will end up in /usr/local/lib or somewhere what is already included

Comment: Hi.. Again.. Here is the file http://collabedit.com/8vc7s

I am not sure where to add what? :( Can you please take a look at the file and make recommendations