# Could not resolve external type warnings in xcode in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, cocos2d-x

I'm using latest cocos2d-x (3.10, precompiled version) with latest xcode (7.2). After some recent xcode update I'm getting a lot of warnings like this (just few different examples):

> warning: Could not resolve external type
>   _ZTSNSt3__16vectorINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEENS4_IS6_EEE24__RAII_IncreaseAnnotatorE
>
> warning: Could not resolve external type
>   _ZTSNSt3__16vectorIPN7cocos2d6SpriteENS_9allocatorIS3_EEE24__RAII_IncreaseAnnotatorE
>
> ld: warning: direct access in
>   cocos2d::Repeat::initWithAction(cocos2d::FiniteTimeAction*, unsigned
>   int) to global weak symbol typeinfo for cocos2d::FiniteTimeAction
>   means the weak symbol cannot be overridden at runtime. This was likely
>   caused by different translation units being compiled with different
>   visibility settings.

Project works well, but this isn't elegant with all these warnings. How can I get rid of them?

When I create new fresh project there aren't any warnings like this (but migrating to new empty project is too troublesome for me).

edit:
Clean and clean build folder don't help.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16353112/299924) as I reckon this is the same thing (the use of the wrong C++ runtime library).

Comment: But I'm using xcode for compilation. I've found in settings that I have "libc++" as c++ standard library..