# Native linking failed xamarin ios in visual studio mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

While I am running my xamarin forms ios project to mac,its showing native linking error:

```
Native linking failed. Please review the build log and the user flags provided to gcc: -ObjC -ObjC -ObjC -lc++ -lz -ObjC -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz (MT5201)
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You're likely not linking against the right C++ library . Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352833/linking-with-clang-on-os-x-generates-lots-of-symbol-not-found-errors .

Comment: I can't understand how to link the c++ library,can you tell me where to add this flags to my xamarin ios project?

Comment: Right click the iOS project ->Properties  -> iOS Build -> mtouch argumrnts .

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Update [Xamarin.Build.Download](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/174411/linker-error-after-adding-xamarin-google-ios-mobileads-nuget) to the latest version.
2. Are there any other errors or only this one? It might be you need to update other libraries (in my case it was google/firebase libs) (and clean bin/obj and package folders of course :) )